# I have recently installed ubuntu 13.04 dual-booting with Windows 7, but can't login.

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 after installing windows 7.Installation was successful but it isn't booting while trying to start the system. System only starts windows 7 and no option for Ubuntu. What is this so? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably did not install grub (boot manager) correctly. Try to repair grub or reinstall Ubuntu ( and choose to install grub to your boot disk ).

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need, to fix your problem

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair